# Bitiwise Const and pointers:

Tags: c++, pointers

I read a line in Meyers:
"A member function that modifies what a pointer points to frequently doesn`t act const.
But if only the pointer is in the object, the function is bitwise const, and compilers wont complain."

I fail to understand that modifying a pointer in a function cannot maintain its bitwise constantness since its a member variable...

Even if we assume that bitwise constantness is only for values that pointers point to and not for the pointer addresses themselves..
Then why does it matter if its the only member variable in the class or if its not the only only member variable..

Comment: That's because the function doesn't modify the pointer. It modifies the object pointed to.

Comment: I think you understood it the other way around.

Comment: The example afterwards I think is pretty clear, you need to explain why the example after that text does not clarify the issue, there is not enough context to properly answer this question. It would also be helpful to explain which book this came from and which item.

Comment: Read that sentence again, carefully.  What you're describing is not what you've quoted.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I understood the answer now..
Will be more clear in posting questions in the future through..

Answer (score 4):

Basically this means that if you had

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar;
};
```

you couldn't have a const member function change the value of `bar`.

However if `bar` is a pointer to an `int`, you could change the value of the int in a const method because the `int` is not actually part of the struct.

Both versions achieve the same goal (i.e. change the value of the `int`) but in the first version you are breaking bitwise constness and the compiler will complain, in the second it wont.

Comment: I rather dispute your final paragraph. Perhaps exchange "semantically" for "functionally"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Better?

Answer (score 2):

It's bitwise `const` because the member function only

> modifies what [the] pointer points to

so the object instace data (the member pointer) doesn't change only the object on the heap that it points to.

Answer (score 1):

Take the following simple classes:

```
class A
{
   public:
      A(int d = 0) : data(d) {}
      void func() const
      {
          ++data; // Can't do this. That's changing
                  // the bitwise content of this.
      }


   private:
      int data;
};
```

And

```
class B
{
   public:
      A(int d = 0) : data(new int(d)) {}
      void func() const
      {
          ++(*data); // Can do this. That doesn't change
                     // the bitwise content of this.
      }


   private:
      int* data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, a member function usually isn't qualified `const` if it modifies a value pointed at by a pointer stored in the current object:

```
class A {
    char*    string;
public:
    void UpCaseString() { strupr(string); }
    ....
}
```

The `UpCaseString()` method modifies data which 'belong' to the object, so it usually would not be declared as const. However it actually modifies some buffer allocated *outside* the current object, the instance of `A` class has only a `char*` pointer to the buffer—so the buffer can still be modified even when the object itself is `const`:

```
class A {
    char*    string;
public:
    void UpCaseString() const { strupr(string); }
    ....
}

void foo(A const &a) {
    a.UpCaseString();
}
```

Member `a.string` is not modified here.